# Can we add an adventure-recommendation tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, game-recommendation

I was looking through the [published-adventure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-adventure) tags looking for some insights on modules to run.  However I was getting a lot of questions that were just noise for me.

I would like to propose adding an [adventure-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-recommendation) tag to separate out those types of questions.   This is different than [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation), because it might be system agnostic, or system specific.

related:  [Has [system-recommendation] grown too big for its britches?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/has-system-recommendation-grown-too-big-for-its-britches)

As an Example.  This question here [The Sunless Citadel and its errors](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28243/the-sunless-citadel-and-its-errors)  is a question which is about a published adventure but not a recommendation.

This question here: [D&D 4e Campaigns/Adventures that spell things out for a brand new DM](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/dd-4e-campaigns-adventures-that-spell-things-out-for-a-brand-new-dm) is a question about a published adventure recommendation.  Also, notice how they added the tag [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) even though they know that they want to play DnD 4e and are not actually asking for a recommendation on a game, but rather just for an adventure.

Comment: What's "noise"? Please explain more clearly what kind of question you imagine remaining tagged [published-adventure], and what kind would get re-labelled [adventure-rec]. What is the useful distinction you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: @BESW updated my question based on your comment.

Answer (score 6):

"Game recommendation" is meant to be read as either a recommendations *of* games to play or recommendations *for* stuff to use with a game.

...No, it's not ideal semantically, but the whole issue of recommendations is full of compromises. The only alternative that we came up with during discussion of the tag (when it changed from [system-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-recommendation) to its current name) was the possibility of using just plain ol' [recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation). That was rejected as being way, way too broad. We also considered [product-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation), but that was rejected on the valid grounds that *systems* are often not 1:1 mappable to *products*, so it was too narrow and narrow in the wrong way.

We couldn't find anything good that covered the middle ground we wanted, so we have [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation), with the advice to read it with an "of" or with a "for", as needed. Tags like [published-adventure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-adventure) can be added to make it clear that it's a recommendation request for adventures, and that makes them nicely searchable by plugging both into the search bar. Searching on:

```
[game-recommendation] [published-adventures]
```

gives you [this list of questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation+published-adventures).

Answer (score 3):

The intent is that [game-recommendation] is the generic shopping tag and it should be modified with [published-adventures] or [campaign-setting] or whatever other product type ([gm-tools]...) you are looking for.  Mod your search accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

### The [published-adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-adventures) tag is pulling weight for that right now.

I'm not sure that there's sufficient distinction between [adventure-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-recommendation) and [published-adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-adventures) to justify adding a new tag to the system. Anyone tagging or searching will find [published-adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-adventures), and there's no useful difference in the kind of expert that would be attracted to the different tags.

Comment: As I explained in the question, the search was muddled with useless information.

Comment: @GMNoob You didn't mention the [published-adventures] tag, just the [adventure] tag.

Comment: Slip on my part! Sorry!  I did not realize there were two tags for [tag:published-adventure] and just [tag:adventure]  But I originally searched by [tag:published-adventure]