# Policy Proposal: Allow Tool-Recommendation Questions

Tags: discussion, policy

[Headnote: in a few places I think linked examples would be nice, but I can neither think of nor find good ones. These are indicated by a "()" after a phrase. Please feel free to plug one in if you think of it. Thanks.]

### The State of Tool-Recommendation

Many questions come to us which presume the existence of a tool which will solve the querent's problem. These questions are often problematic: often [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), often [too broad](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67597/23970), often primarily opinion-based(). These, and more, are the reason that recommendation ("shopping") questions are *non grata* in all of the SE sites().

Until recently RPG.SE had an explicit, local policy allowing for [recommendation questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1070/23970). This policy was recently debated [in meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5711/23970)--largely in the context of the game-recommendation tag--and [revoked](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/23970). It appears that many users did not realize that removing the (local) policy allowing game-rec questions--the larger "allow recommendation questions" policy--[would also be the undoing of tool-rec questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5843/23970).

I confess to being one of those surprised by tool-rec questions losing the support of the now-defunct "allow recommendation questions" policy. I had followed the conversation with my eye toward game-rec questions. I also confess that had I understood better at the time the "allow recommendation questions" policy that ramification might have been obvious. (Though [maybe not](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5721/23970).) *Yes, the policy that allowed for game-recs also supported tool-recs; tool-recs thus lost their support when game-recs did.*

Nevertheless, from the answers and comments to many of the above-linked and from recent meta discussions we see that there is a desire in this community to provide assistance to these querents.

Cribbing largely from meta discussions had at softwarerecs.SE--[pointed out by @AngleoFuchs](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5863/23970)--I put forth the following proposal:

### Tool-Recommendation Question Guidelines (Proposed 10/2015)

Recognize that successful Tool-Recommendation questions contain two *essential* components: a goal to accomplish and a set of requirements to be met.

Question Content must describe
- the task you're doing when you find yourself having trouble; the "user story"

- ways in which your current 'solution' succeeds and fails--what it does and doesn't do
- other things you've tried
- what you hope to achieve--a desired feature list
- what you absolutely do not want--things that would cause you to reject a solution untried
- what level of tech is acceptable/allowable: pen-and-paper, laptops, online, must run on phone-only, &c.
- what budget you have

Recommended Question Format:

- "What is the *best* tool to ?" Is to be avoided. Prefer "How can I ?"
- Don't say you're looking for a replacement for X; tell us what you do with X that you're hoping to do differently/better.
- Feature requirements should be listed in order of importance, with a clear distinction drawn between must-haves and gee-that-would-be-nices.

Comment: I don't believe we should be following this up by proposing policies in questions, let alone questions we've posted only to post a self-answer rejecting the policy therein. I've taken more than long enough to post the question I'd said I would, which opens this up to open discussion where policy can be proposed as answers. I'm voting to close this as a dupe of that.

Comment: After some thought, I added my close vote to @doppelgreener's - while this post is well written and reasoned, it would be cleaner to have a clear question post so that the meaning of votes is clearer. That said, I think the answer you gave here is excellent and should be ported over post-haste.

Comment: If that answer's brought to my question, please do take care to address the nature of the question I asked in the process. It will probably need some rewriting.

Comment: @doppelgreener absolutely--sorry to have jumped into the fray before you. I'll VtC, too. I don't have time today to take much of a look at yours and bring over my answer, but it'll happen soon.

Comment: @nitsua60 It's fine, I should've posted that question way earlier. There's a lot of fray to jump into and it was asking for _something_ to happen.

Comment: Feel free and post this as an answer on the other question.

Answer (score 3):

My answer:

### Reject

I've come around on this one during the last two weeks. I initially was very surprised to see tool-rec questions' ground fall out from under them; I'd not understood the rec-policy well enough while discussing game-rec to understand both would fall.

But a week of reflection and reading has convinced me that an explicit exception to the recommendation ban is unnecessary. In particular, TuggyNE's link to (an answer to) [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185486) helped me see how much better a hypothetical tool-rec question becomes if simply cast as a problem-question. *I.e.* a "How can I do *this*?" question rather than a "What's the best tool to do *this*?"

I haven't had any sort of privileges long enough to understand why and how the exception it's a *bad* thing; but I [assume good faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Assume_good_faith) and believe those longer-time users who say it's a lot of work to curate/moderate.

I believe we can still help those querents get good answers, inherently improve the questions, and make less work for mods, by rejecting a tool-rec exception to the rec-ban. (Or creating a new local permission for tool-rec questions, however you like to think of it.)

My takeaway:

*A tool-rec can still be part of an **answer**; it shouldn't be a requirement in the **question.***

Comment: Feel free and post this as an answer on the other question.

Comment: @mxyzplk Honestly, I just re-read your answer on the live question and re-read mine. Mine only looks (to me) like a poorer-supported, less well-described, version of yours. I'm inclined to delete mine, as I think it doesn't really add anything to that conversation. Or do you think it's useful having a little "weight of numbers," or having the same argument made from a different perspective?

Comment: Either way, just vote unless you have something different to add, but similar-not-quite-identical answers are fine esp on meta...