# Is a question asking for a resource list of places to find developer commentary on the construction of D&D 5e's rules on-topic and wanted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, dnd-5e, designer-reasons

We have the following relevant Meta Q&A which covers the topicality of asking for commentary on *specific* rules (they are currently considered off-topic):

- [Are questions about rule intent on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964)

However we now also have the following Mainsite question:

- [Where can I find official commentaries by the D&D 5e designers on why they designed certain rules the way they did?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171772)

Is such a question workable or on-topic for this site? It would amount to listing things such as the Dragon Talk Podcast, Sage Advice Compendium, Twitter, YouTube, and perhaps also using the [WayBack Machine](https://archive.org/web/) to find things like the [Dragon Article Archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20140708123204/http://wizards.com/dnd/Archive.aspx?category=dragon).

Something I'm at least seeing is a similarity between such a question and the following Meta post which is effectively a resource list:

- [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449)

Of course, there's a **glaringly massive difference**; the above post is broad and applies to any question which fits better at a forum whereas the sort of post I'm asking about **applies entirely and exclusively to the fifth edition of Dungeons & Dragons**. This gives me worries about the site seeming *even more* to be a D&D 5e site if we had such a Q&A catered specifically to this one game and not any others. Thus, I'm left wondering two things:

Is this sort of question on-topic? Regardless, is this a question we even *want* (would allowing it cause harm)?

Comment: If the wording or phrasing of this post seems aggressive or weird I apologize for that. I'm not entirely sure how to ask whether or not such a question would be unfair to TTRPGs that are not dnd-5e besides asking if we "want" it. If people know a better wording, I would appreciate suggestions/edits

Comment: An observation, but not quite an answer to the actual question: While a question of "where can I find official D&D 5e rulings" has a clearly limited list of possible answers (there used to be two places; now there's just one), a question of "where can I find any of the designers making any statements related to D&D" seems... potentially very wide-ranging in the list of possible answers (the answer's basically "anywhere any of the designers could say anything D&D-related").

Answer (score 6):

It is off topic on rpg.se because recommendation/shopping questions are off topic -game-recs, but also tool and resource  and site recs.  See [Are tool recommendation questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/are-tool-recommendation-questions-on-topic/5883#5883)

We have a list of forums on Meta because it’s off-topic for the main site as a rec question, but we felt having a “where to go when you get told to go to a forum” list was useful at a site meta level.  I do not think rules research for one game is similarly useful at a site administration level so would vote to close such a question on meta.

Answer (score 1):

It's trivially editable-- instead of asking *where* it should ask *how*, the answer to which is probably 'go to such and such a site', but that's allowed.