# Is this question about an Ordinary Items Database an off-topic tool recommendation question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Here is the question: [Looking For Historically Accurate Ordinary Items Database For Dungeon-Stocking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/174570/62294)

[Tool recommendation questions are off-topic on rpg.se](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5883/62294). Is this question a tool recommendation question?

Answer (score 6):

#### This question is off-topic.

This question asks for a tool that serves a certain purpose, particularly, a database that lists common items found in various rooms at different points in history.

#### 1. This is not an RPG question.

That this question relates to RPGs at all is because its answer may be useful for worldbuilding (which there is a stack for already) and it may have appeared in the comments section of a Matt Colville video one time. This is evident by OP's description of where it may have come from:

> The data may have come from the insurance industry; lists of personal property itemized just in case a future claim would need to be made against an insurance policy, renter's insurance, and the like.

This database was not created for RPGs by RPG players, and so RPG expertise is likely not required or even useful for answering the question.

It is probably better suited for History.se or Worldbuilding.se.

#### 2. "I've seen this before" does not make it not tool recommendation.

The only difference between this and something that is explicitly a textbook tool recommendation is "I swear I saw it one time". If we remove this from the post, the question becomes "I'm looking for a tool that does these things" - tool recommendation. The "I've seen this before" bit of the question just gives you a place to start looking for tools to recommend.

*This is tool recommendation thinly veiled as product identification.*