# What are our requirements for tool recommendation questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, tools

Tool recommendations are a fairly popular category of question (found in [tool-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-recommendation), and a lot of them are simply tagged [tools](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools)). Being recommendations, these questions and answers need to go a bit further than most questions to be of good quality for the site, and are more prone to run into problems.

Most of the time, things work themselves out well, but we still have problematic patches and answers that say little more than *"here, try this: {link}"*. We have no policy or guidance tailored specifically to tool recommendations to point these people to, and it's probably about time we did have that.

What are our requirements for tool recommendation questions and answers? What guidance can we give to authors to have their questions and answers work well within our system? If parts of our [policy for game recommendations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1070/1204) applies, what applies?

(Please elaborate or summarise the requirements: the intention here is that we can link people to this question and they'll understand the basics of what we need from them.)

Comment: The impetus for this was a user having a poor enough experience due to problematic advice they decided to pursue deleting their own account. I think we need some centralised and agreed-upon guidance tailored specifically to tool recommendations that we can link to people when they're having problems.

Comment: I wonder if maybe instead of [game-recommendation], we *should* just have a general [recommendation] tag (or just [shopping]) to hang our "shopping question" rules on, despite that old meta...

Answer (score 3):

All the game-rec stuff applies.  Per [Has [system-recommendation] grown too big for its britches?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/has-system-recommendation-grown-too-big-for-its-britches/3006#3006) we decided not to do a whole bunch of extra tagging (tool-rec! Adventure-rec!) for stuff that surfaces once in a blue moon.

Comment: Are you able to summarise the game-rec stuff and how it applies to tool recommendations? My intention is for answers here to be something we can link users to, and they'll read it and understand what we need from them.